# Trying to get the custom Post type category link in Wordpress for the current post as meta data of the post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to place a link to the Artist of a video in a custom post type in WordPress. Everything is working but the term_id does not iterate.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'video',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'taxonomy' => $term->name,
    'number' => $term->term_id,
);
        
$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();        
        //Your template tags and markup like:
        ?>
        
      <div class="card">
          <div class="bg-img"><img  alt="Norway" style="width:100%" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );?></div>
          <div class="content">
            <h4 style="color: green;"><?php the_title( ); ?></h4>
             <h5 class="artist-name"><?php
  
  $terms = get_terms( $args );
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
  
        echo '<div style="color: black;"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, 'band' ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . " ". $term->term_id . '</a></div>'; 
            
    }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it seems that you are using the posts arguments for "get_terms" which is not correct and that's why you are not getting the correct term's data.

You can check the query parameter of terms [over here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) to get the idea.

Comment: If this answer helps you, please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks!